Is it possible to ignore pyright linting only for magic commands IPython command
It's possible to use the # type: ignore comment to ignore linting on a specific line:
print(syntax error) # type: ignore

However, the same is not possible with magic commands:
%load_ext autoreload # type: ignore

'''
yields error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autoreload # type: ignore'"
'''

Removing it, however, yields the linting error "Expected expression". And of course, using # type: ignore in the top of the file is not desirable, as it would disable all linting for the whole file.
Is it possible to disable PyRight linting for magic commands?

You understand the problem, right?  PyRight is a Python checker, and those %-escaped commands are not Python at all.  If you tried to run your script as-is in Python, it would also fail.

@TimRoberts Yes, that doesn't change my question at all. In specific, I'm using Jupyter Ascending to convert from .py to .ipynb. Not an uncommon use-case.

For you, maybe.  Most Python users don't use .ipynb files.  However, my point is that you could ask the Pyright developer community (which is fairly active) for a feature request.
